# Vertical lines in this diophantine equation?

Tags: number-theory

I'm looking into diophantine equations and see the property that any two solutions to a diophantine equation create a line that intersects the equation at a different solution. However, what about vertical lines through the graph of $y^2 = x^3 - 2x$. I'm assuming there's a detail about this property I'm not picking up on.

Is there some reason it doesn't count to have a vertical line with our P and Q that finds a third point R?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to specify that the property holds for rational solutions and I don't know if it holds for all real solutions.

Comment: It is a property of cubic equations that from two rational points you have a 3rd point (look at the 3rd root of $h(t) = f(a+ct,b+dt) = -c^3 t (t-1)(t-T)$ where $f(x,y)  =y^2-x^3+2x, f(a,b)=f(a+c,b+d)=0$)

Comment: The theorem you are thinking about requires that you count tangency as a double root, and pay attention to solutions "at infinity". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law

Comment: Could you elaborte on what tou mean by "count tangency as a double root"?

Comment: The quadratic curve $y=x^2$ looks as if it has just one root, at $0$. But that root is really a double root. $x$ is a factor twice. The geometry that reflects that algebra shows up because the $x$-axis is tangent to the parabola at the origin. You have to understand multiple roots of polynomials before you can make sense of what you are reading about elliptic curves.

Comment: Can you not put a vertical line through the equation to find two solutions? Are solitions just x-y coordinates on the curve? Can you not have two distinct solutions with the same x value?